# Streaming MimeBodyPart Text

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have to send an email with a large String in the body of the mail( not as an attachement) , i can read the String from a file.

My question is  : how can i set my large string in text with streaming ?

```
MimeBodyPart.setText(text);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use:

```
public MimeBodyPart(java.io.InputStream is) throws MessagingException
```

It seems there is a constructor with stream, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#MimeBodyPart%28java.io.InputStream%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the input stream must be for the attachement , no? because i hava already an atechment + large String to paste in Text mail.

Comment: I have another question please, the constructor with stream seems to be working,do you know how can i set the size of the buffer for the stream?because it take a lot of time to stream,Thanks

Comment: Take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#BufferedInputStream(java.io.InputStream, int)

Comment: new BufferedInputStream(YourInputStream, BufferSize)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the setText method, you need to use the setDatahandler method, and you need to create a DataHandler based on a FileDataSource.

```
msg.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(file)));
```